# How to remove floating teardrops after removing the object they were attached to in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium

I removed a via and the tracks connected to it after removing the associated net and this left the teardrops in place; impossible to select, and not getting removed with "remove all" in the teardrop tool. I also found another one that was left when using "delete/all" and exhibits identical behavior despite the objects it was attached to still existing.

How do I get rid of them?

[image: picture of one of the teardrops]
[image: second teardrop]

Comment: Have you read the manual or looked for answers on Altium and it's many associated partners?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, of course, I failed to find anything that would be useful in this scenario, thus the question.

Comment: Please list the altium resources you attempted to use that were unsuccessful so that folk attempting the same route can avoid them. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: This may be a silly suggestion by have you tried removing the floaters manually, by selecting and deleting manually ? Do you have many floaters or is it just this one track ?

Comment: @citizen I have, they don't get selected regardless of selection options. I found another that doesn't fit the scenario I though caused those, I'll update the question.

Comment: @Jan. Is there a possibility that you cannot select the offending floaters because they are "locked". Perhaps making sure all tracks and regions are unlocked temporarily and try again ?

Comment: @citizen closing and opening the file made them possible to select, no idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing and reopening the file the teardrops were possible to select and delete using the "Regions" selection filter.

[image: selection filter]
[image: selected teardrop]

Comment: Yes I have noticed they're rendered as regions ... well I guess some kind of glitch/bug somewhere - maybe nothing to do with Altium per se ...

Comment: @citizen I'm pretty sure it didn't work before reopening the file but I can't deny this might just be user error